# GHCI to external file

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a Haskell function which returns quite a large output. (In fact, beyond the console's buffer size.) Is there any way GHCI output can be automatically saved to an external txt file rather than simply displayed?

Comment: The result of the last command is bound to the variable `it`.  You can `writeFile "filename.txt" it`.  Or `writefile "filename.txt" $ <statement>`.

Comment: Tried that, not working. The point is my function returns [Integer] and writeFile seems to expect [Char]. Any ideas on how I could fix that? @vivian

Comment: @DarioP: If it is an instance of `Show`, just use `writeFile "filename.txt" $ show it`.

Comment: @zeta I get "not in scope id, did you mean id"... thoughts?

Comment: @DarioP: Yes - `it` stores the result of the last command. If there hasn't been a last statement with a value (for instance, all statements have been `let ...` expressions), `it` will be not in scope. So basically take vivian's comment, but put a `$ show` before your statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the last command is bound to the variable it.

You can

`writeFile "filename.txt" $ show it`

or

`writefile "filename.txt" $ show $ <statement>`