# Prevent function from printing to screen

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am currently using GHCI to measure the runtime of several functions. As these functions produce quite a long output which I'm not interested in, I was wondering if there was any way from preventing such outputs to be displayed to the screen and only display runtime obtained via: :set + s

Comment: I assume this is different than your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122684/ghci-to-external-file)?

Comment: @FelixKling yes, I need both to record the complete output (function output + runtime) as well as only the runtimes in two separate files.

Comment: You can call length or last or something like that on the resulting string to make sure it is fully evaluated instead of printing it. You could also use `Control.Exception.evaluate` or `Control.DeepSeq`

Comment: @user2407038 Depending on the example, `length` might not cut it, as it will only evaluate to WHNF. Same with `last`: it might compute the last element, but leave the others at WNHF. I'd recommend mapping `force` over a list, from `Control.DeepSeq`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use [`criterion`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) to measure the runtime. It takes care of evaluating results of pure functions to (WH)NF, repeating the test several times etc.

If you want to hide the output, while still keeping everything being evaluated, I'd suggest you to parametrize your code with respect to output. For example, by a [`Handle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#t%3aHandle), or simply by a function of type `String -> IO ()`. Then you can easily redirect the output to a file, to `/dev/null`, or in the latter case even just force its evaluation by passing `evaluate . rnf`.